# Extra vertical space when using tcolorbox

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, vertical-alignment, tcolorbox

Here's my code -

```
\documentclass[12pt,x11names]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{Powder blue}{HTML}{A8DADC}


\usepackage{garamondlibre}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

%geometry package
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{papersize={23cm,28cm}, right=9.3cm, left=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=3cm, marginparwidth=4.8cm, marginparsep=1.5cm, headheight=0cm}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=Powder blue!50!white, colframe=Powder blue!50!white,ams equation]
\ce{N2(g) + 3H2 (g) -> 2NH3(g)} \tag{ \Delta \textbf{H}_{r}^{\ominus} = -92\ \unit{kJ}}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

For some reason, I'm getting extra vertical space -
[image]

How do I remove this extra vertical space?

Comment: Maybe using `top=0pt,bottom=0pt` as options to the box?

Comment: I don't know why but looks like `\ce` is adding the vertical space above the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,x11names]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\definecolor{Powder blue}{HTML}{A8DADC}


\usepackage{garamondlibre}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

%geometry package
\usepackage[papersize={23cm,28cm}, 
            hmargin={3cm, 9.3cm}, vmargin={2.5cm, 3cm}, 
            marginparwidth=4.8cm, marginparsep=1.5cm, 
            headheight=0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=Powder blue!50!white, colframe=Powder blue!50!white, ams gather*]  % <---
\ce{N2(g) + 3H2 (g) -> 2NH3(g)} \qquad(\Delta\mathbf{H}_{r}^{\ominus} = \qty{-92}{kJ})  % <---
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Changes in comparison with your MWE:

- used is option `ams gather*`
- removed is `\tag` and instead of it inserted `\qquad` distance
- used is `siunitx` package

**addendum:**

It also works fine by use of `\tag`:

```
...
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=Powder blue!50!white, 
                  colframe=Powder blue!50!white, 
                  ams gather]  % <---
\ce{N2(g) + 3H2 (g) -> 2NH3(g)} \tag{$\Delta\mathbf{H}_{r}^{\ominus} = \qty{-92}{kJ}$}  % <---
\end{tcolorbox}
...
```

Compilation result is almost the same as before:

[image]

Comment: Do you agree that the problem is caused by `\ce`?

Comment: @Sigur, is hard to say. It seems, that `\ce`  doesn't work well with `equation`  environment  (which is more complex than `gather`), but sufficient well with `ams` math environments (in `tcolorbox`). So, on my answer can be look as workaround  how to solve OP problem.